# Ansible "connection closed" using AWS .pem file with Dynamic Inventory

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Ansible is failing with a "connection closed" error when using an AWS .pem file. Yet I can connect OK via ssh using the same file. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

I have a couple of servers in AWS set-up with dynamic inventory (ignore the one without a public IP I know that won't work):

```
$ ansible-inventory -i aws_ec2.yaml --graph

@all:
  |--@aws_ec2:
  |  |--ec2-34-244-225-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
  |  |--ip-10-128-1-129.eu-west-1.compute.internal
  |--@ungrouped:
```

I can happily connect to the server with a public ip as follows:

```
$ ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/my-dev.pem openvpnas@ec2-34-244-225-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Welcome to OpenVPN Access Server Appliance 2.8.5

  System information as of Wed Aug  5 18:17:25 UTC 2020
etc.
```

But when I try to use Ansible with the same .pem file it fails with a connection closed error, and I don't know why.

```
$ ansible all -i aws_ec2.yaml -a ‘uptime’ \
--private-key=$HOME/.ssh/my-dev.pem \
--become-user=openvpnas
.
.
.
ec2-34-244-225-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection closed by 34.244.225.4 port 22", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Is this a .pem file funny, or something to do with dynamic inventory. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess your inventory needs `ansible_user=openvpnas` set; try running ansible at higher verbosity to see what it's actually attempting to do

Comment: I second the observation of @mdaniel - you are specifying `become-user`, but not `ssh-user`, which Ansible will also need

Comment: Thanks all, I'd convinced myself it was something to do with dynamic inventory. Obvious when someone points it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--become-user` is to run operation as that user. Try with `--user openvpnas` in the command or you can set it ansible.cfg file as `remote_user = openvpnas`